# How can I get the last clicked index from a NodeList?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the last clicked index of NodeList using querySelector?

If:
click on "RED" checkbox returns index 0
click on "GREEN" checkbox returns index 1
click on "BLUE" checkbox returns index 2

```js
let lastClickedIndex = document.querySelector(".rgbClass").index( ? );

document.querySelector(".rgbClass")[1].checked = true; /* GREEN will appear as checked */
```

```html
<input name="colors[]" value="RED" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass">RED<br>
<input name="colors[]" value="GREEN" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass">GREEN<br>
<input name="colors[]" value="BLUE" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass">BLUE<br>
```

console.log(`document.querySelector(".rgbClass")`):

```
NodeList(3) [input.rgbClass, input.rgbClass, input.rgbClass]

0: input.rgbClass
1: input.rgbClass
2: input.rgbClass
length: 3

[[Prototype]]: NodeList
```

Comment: If you *specifically* only want the last clicked checkbox, you need to set click event listeners, which stores the value locally. But I assume it is not what you really want to achieve

Comment: if I click on the GREEN box, I want it to store the number 1 in a variable, corresponding to the NodeList index.

Comment: Index specifically in relation to the NodeList, or indeed among its siblings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use onClick event

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll(".rgbClass");

let lastClickedIndex = null;
 
all.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener("click", onClick);
});

function onClick(){
  lastClickedIndex = [...all].indexOf(this);
  console.log('Last index:', lastClickedIndex);
}
```

```html
<input name="colors[]" value="RED" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass"><br>
<input name="colors[]" value="GREEN" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass"><br>
<input name="colors[]" value="BLUE" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass"><br>
```

To remember last clicked index I have used (spread) `[...all]` which converts nodelist to an array, and get index of clicked node.
Then you can do whatever you want with `lastClickedIndex`

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Get all elements with rgbClass class
document.querySelectorAll(".rgbClass").forEach(checkbox =>
    // for each element add a click event listener 
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        // get the currently clicked element
        const currentCheckbox = event.currentTarget;
        // get the parent
        const parent = currentCheckbox.parentElement;
        // get the checkboxes siblings -> children of parent with rgbClass class
        const checkboxes = [...parent.childNodes].filter(element =>
            element?.classList?.contains('rgbClass') ?? false
        );
        // get the index of the current checkbox in array of all checkboxes
        const checkboxIndex = checkboxes.indexOf(currentCheckbox);
        console.log(`clicked ${checkboxIndex} index`);
    })
 );
```

```html
<input name="colors[]" value="RED" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass">RED<br>
<input name="colors[]" value="GREEN" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass">GREEN<br>
<input name="colors[]" value="BLUE" type="checkbox" class="rgbClass">BLUE<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Our goal is to find out which input was clicked and display it in the console.

**Note :** If you click on the input again, it is ignored

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>select checkbox</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input id='red' name='colors' value='red' type='checkbox' class='rgb'>
        <label for='red'>red</label>
        <br>
        <input id='green' name='colors' value='green' type='checkbox' class='rgb'>
        <label for='green'>green</label>
        <br>
        <input id='blue' name='colors' value='blue' type='checkbox' class='rgb'>
        <label for='blue'>blue</label>
        <br>
    </form>
    <script>
        const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.rgb');

        let authItems = [];

        nodeList.forEach((item, index) => {
            item.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(this, index));
        })

        function handler(num) {
            if (authItems.includes(num)) {
                authItems = authItems.filter((item) => item !== num);
            }
            else {
                authItems.push(num);
            }
            authItems.sort();
            console.log(authItems.toString() || 'EMPTY ;)');
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```